# How to transfer file from PC (windows 7) to Mainframe either using script or FTP?

Tags: ftp, mainframe

I want to transfer from my local drive to mianframe either using script or FTP without opening mainframe .Please help me .Any help is valuable .Thanks in advance.

I tried this Step1:
Start --> Run --> Command
Step2:  Enter the following command 
FTP XX.XXX.XX.XXX
Where XX.XXX.XX.XXX  is the ip address of mainframe 
Step3: When you are prompted for user name and password, provide your mainframe id and mainframe password
Step4:
To Upload the file to mainframe from PC
PUT D:\MYFILES\TEST.TXT 'FILE.ON.MAINFRAM'...............PUT "PC file path (e.g. c:\xxxxxxxx)" "mainframe file name
"

Where 
FILE.ON.MAINFRAM is the file on mainframe
and
D:\MYFILES\TEST.TXT - is the file on PC

**when I enter the FTP and opening using ip it is showing connected to Ip but not asking for user name and password.**

Comment: Ask at your site. If they want you to do this, they will know the way they want you to do it. If they don't want you to do it, don't attempt it anyway, let alone with random suggestions from the internet.

Comment: What have you tried already?  What were the results?  What do you mean by "without opening mainframe?"  Does that mean "without using a 3270 emulator?"

Comment: Insted of opening emulator and selecting upload option manually is there any possibility to upload file using FTP.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to your site.  Yes, FTP exists on mainframes, but your site has to have it enabled.  What you are seeing suggests they don't have it enabled, or possibly have some sort of security set up, like FTPS.  Emulators may also allow you to upload a file as well, but again, it's up to your site.

Comment: I’m already a sponsor of that proposal. As for why I suspect it isn’t enabled:  something is on port 23, or you’d get connection refused/timeout. But it doesn’t respond to an FTP client, so that suggests something is in the way, or there’s a different protocol expected, like FTPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you got connected that means that the MF is running a FTP server so one step is done.

The mainframe FTP is a bit different and may not ask for a user and pw rather it waits for you to provide it - use `USER username` and `PASS password` once connected.

Here is [a list of FTP commands](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu001/ftpsubcmd.htm) that will come in handy. Remember to set transfer `TYPE` and transfer `MODE`